# Javascript regular expression should allows empty and non-empty string, but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a regular expression that allows a string to be empty. If it isn't empty the string may contain only letters and spaces. But it may not start or end with a space.

This RegExp should do this job:
`^(?! )[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z ]*$`
I've tested it here: http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/

But when I'm implementing this in my js, it doesn't allow a string to be empty.

This is the code

```
function validatePreposition(name) {
    string = string = document.forms['form'][name].value;
    pattern = new RegExp('^(?! )[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z ]*$');

    checkString(name, pattern, string);
}

function checkString(name, pattern, string) {

    if(!pattern.test(string)) {
        error[name] = 1;
    } else {
        error[name] = 0;
    }

    printErrors();
}
```

How change my code so that an empty string is allowed?

Comment: What is the `(?! )` for?

Comment: @Jergason negative lookahead: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; `/^(?! )[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test("") === true`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
pattern = /(^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*$)|(^$)/;
```

It will either test for an empty string or test for a string that starts with a a-Z and may have unlimited amount of spaces in the string but have to end with a-Z.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/BAXya/

Comment: @OrangeTux You're welcome :) Don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Could also use this:

```
if (subject.match(/^(?=[a-z ]*$)(?=\S)(?=.*\S$)/i)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

Using only lookaheads. Although I would go with @Marcus answer.